# Rendering new component on-click in a parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a button component called `CreateTicket` and a component I want to render on click called `IndividualTicketInput`. I have created a parent component where I currently have both of these. I need to have a function that renders a new ticket component on-click in the parent component underneath the first `IndividualTicketInput` and so forth. I know I have to push into the tickets array but I am still learning react and having trouble understanding the concepts. How would you best go about this and if you need clarity on my end please let me know.

button component

```
var CreateTicket = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return{};
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <button type="button" className="add-another-ticket">
        +Add Ticket
      </button>
    );
  }
})
```

Ticket Component **(this is the component I want to render on click)

```
var IndividualTicketInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { ticket: {name: '', quantity: '', price: null} };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label>Ticket Name</label>
          <input className="ticket-name" type="text" placeholder="E.g. General Admission" value={this.state.ticket.name} />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label>Quantity Available</label>
          <input className="quantity" type="number" placeholder="100" value={this.state.ticket.quantity} />
        </li>
          <li>
            <label>Price</label>
            <input className="price" type="number" placeholder="25.00" value={this.state.ticket.price} />
          </li>
        <li>
          <button type="button" className="delete-ticket" onClick={this.deleteTicket}><i className="fa fa-trash-o delete-ticket"></i></button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Tickets Component

```
var Tickets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {tickets: [] };
  },
  createNewTicket: function() {

    // where the push happens on click to create the new IndividualTicketInput component

    // this is what I am currently trying but it isn't working
    var tickets = this.state.tickets;
     this.state.tickets.push(
      <IndividualTicketInput />
    )
    this.forceUpdate();

  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IndividualTicketInput />
        // new component will render here
        <div>{this.state.tickets}</div>
        <CreateTicket onClick={this.createNewTicket} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got this working. Attached props to the child button component and then passed through the component using push.

button component

```
var CreateTicket = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return{};
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <button type="button" onClick={this.props.createTicket} className="add-another-ticket">
        +Add Ticket
      </button>
    );
  }
})
```

Tickets component:

```
var Tickets = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      tickets: []
    }
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log('this mounted')
  },
  onClick: function() {
    this.state.tickets.push(
      <IndividualTicketInput />
    )
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IndividualTicketInput />
        {this.state.tickets}
        <CreateTicket createTicket={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The only problem I run into now is the key situation but I will figure it out. Thanks all that took a look at this.

Comment: One thing I'd like to add - in React, you should never mutate state directly. So, instead of saying `this.state.tickets.push()`, you should do something like: `var newState = this.state; newState.tickets.push(//whatever); this.setState(newState); `

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Makes sense